# Recursive looping in r

Tags: r

I am new in R but I want to loop through elements of a given list recursively, to be presice I have alist of vectors where the first vector is given by (1,2,3,4), then I now want to loop through this vector and append the second vector obtained to the original list, again loop thorugh second vector in the list and get the third vector which is also appended on the original list and so on. I have this code to start with`

```
occlist <- list()
occ_cell <- c(1,2,3,4)

for(i in occ_cell){
  occ_cell <- seq(i,4*i, by = 1)
  occlist[[i]] <- occ_cell
}
`
```

gives the following list

```
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4

#[[2]]
#[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

#[[3]]
# [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12

#[[4]]
# [1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

I think to be more clear, lets have the following figure

[image: In that image we have 2 levels and the values in each level should be appended to a list, again each level is computed from the previous level.(i.e. in level two we have values obtained from level one (1,2,3,4,) and values from level one is obtained from level 0 (1)]

Comment: why? is there a question in there some where? why are you losing the first (few) element(s) of each vector. I assumed you would want this `lapply(4 * 1:4, sequence)`

Answer (score 3):

```
recOcc <- function(i) {
    if (i == 0) return ( NULL )
    append( recOcc(i-1), list(seq(i, 4*i)) )
}
```

And, call with (to reproduce your output)

```
recOcc(4)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
# 
# [[3]]
#  [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
# 
# [[4]]
#  [1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

You can also use `Recall` to name your recursive function in the recursive call, which allows for the function name to change.

#### Edit

For the tree structure, you could try this

```
## i is the number to start the sequence
## depth determines how deep to recurse
recOcc2 <- function(i, depth=3, cur.depth=0) {
    if (depth==cur.depth) return(seq(i, 4*i))
    acc <- as.list(seq(i, 4*i))
    for (ii in seq_along(acc))
        acc[[ii]] <- recOcc2(acc[[ii]], depth, cur.depth+1)
    acc
}

## To recreate the simple list
res <- recOcc2(1, depth=1)

## For nested lists
res <- recOcc2(1, depth=2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, however, i think my question wasn't well framed, am working with tree of values whereby on the first level of the tree we have value 1, in the second level we have values (1,2,3,4) and values in the third level are derived from second level, such that for 1 in the second level we have(1,2,3,4) in the third level, for 2 in the second level we have (2,3,4,5,6,7,8) in the thrid level, for 3 in the second we have (3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) and for four in second level we have (4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16). So the loop is intended to compute this recursively.

Comment: @EvansOtieno I'm not sure I understood, but try the edit and see if that works.

Comment: I wish I could attach the copy of what I want but their option for attaching or is there a way I can write equation so that you can have the real picture of what I want

Comment: @EvansOtieno does the edit work?  To access elements in level 2 of your picture, for example the 4th component, you would do `res[[1]][[4]]`